# Parsing nested elements using iterparse() or findall()

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml

I have xml documents (encoded with UTF-8) with a structure of:

```
<Group id= "123">
    <rule id= "abc" level= "low">
    <identity>some text</identity>
    <element1>text</element1>
</Group>
```

Each document has multiple Group elements, the goal is to parse them into a spreadsheet where each group is a row with columns of group id, level, and the text from identity and element1 elements.

I have a script using findall() that works when I try to parse one document at a time, but when I try and parse many documents at once it tends to fail out with an error stating:

```
 File "c:/Documents/Python Projects/Bulkparse.py", line 86, in parseall
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9d' in position 1137: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've looked up the '\x9d' character code, it seems to be some kind of cross icon, which does not appear in any of my documents. So I'm sure where or why it happens.

Findall() script example:

```
for child in root.findall('Group'):
  data.append(child.attrib['id'])
  num = child.attrib['id']
  for child in root.findall('Group[@id = "%s"]/Rule'% num ):
    data.append(child.attrib['level'])
    # followed by a for loop for each element needed ending with
    writer.writerow(data)
```

The above works, unless I'm doing a bulk job, which gives me the above error.

Is it just that the findall() is too inefficient? I've attempted writing something with iterparse() but can't find a way to make it iterate through each each of the child elements. For example:

```
for  event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag ==f"Group" and event == 'end':
        data.append(elem.attrib['id'])
        num = elem.attrib['id']
        for event, elem in context :
            if elem.tag ==f"Rule" and event == 'end':
                data.append(elem.attrib['level'])
                print(data)
```

returns the group id, followed by the level rating for EACH group so [123, low, high, low, low, low, high..] etc.

Is it better to use the iterparse? If so, is there a way for me to have it target element tags nested in the group element, like I did with the findall()?
Or is there a way to get the findall() script to stop throwing that error? Is there a way to clear the memory at the end of each document? (Assuming that would help)
The help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace. Decoding/encoding errors are usually related to reading/writing a file (or similar stream), of which nothing is shown in the code.

Comment: The error indicates some encoding mismatch. In UTF-8, `9d` is a continuation byte (should not occur in isolation). In the cp1252 encoding, `9d` is undefined.

Comment: Since the error is thrown by ``writer.writerow(data)`` – what is ``writer``?

Answer (score 0):

Find out which document is causing the problem, by splitting your document set and searching the half that continues to raise the error. While you say  '\x9d' is not in your document set as far as you can see, it must be in there in a different encoding.

You haven't said what character encoding the XML documents have - perhaps change the character encoding of the XML to UTF?

If you can't see a problem with the encoding, you could switch your export process to an XSL transform that does an XML to csv conversion. This may be better anyway.

Comment: they use the UTF-8 encoding, I set it up to specify the encoding value as Jack suggested, and it doesn't seem to have had any effect @Bryn Lewis

Answer (score -1):

This problem comes up frequently when reading files with unusual characters. One way to try to resolve it is to do the following when you open your xml file:

```
with open('myfile.xml', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
   root = etree.XML(myfile)  #or however you import lxml and your file
   for child in root.findall('Group'):.....
```

This would take care of the majority of these problem. But I have encountered so many of these errors, I had to resort, on occasion, to actually editing the more troublesome charcters out of the file before processing it. Something like:

```
[string representation of your file].replace('\x9d','+') 
#or whatever other charcter you want to use to represent a cross.
```